# JavaScript Regex: Want to match different strings within a URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm hoping you guys can help.

I'm looking to match a number of different strings within a set of URLs.

Given I have the following URLS:

```
http://one.com
http://two.com
http://three.com
http://four.com
```

I want to write one regex line which looks for the words:

```
one
two
three
```

returning the first three URLs.

I can do this with absolute matches, but I am struggling when looking within a longer string.

Thanks.

Comment: What have your tried? What is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Irritatingly, just after writing this - I managed to get it to work:

```
.*(one|two|three).*
```

Was a lot simpler than I was attempting prior.

Comment: what if i have from one to millions :p